# Android newbie problem: restarting an application

Tags: android

I have an Android app that works fine the first time you run it.
However, when you press HOME (so it pauses), and restart it from the home screen all I get is the music restarted.

I've not yet got to the stage of saving/restoring states yet (will do soon!).
It seems that the main update thread is not resuming.

It calls `onRestart()` fine...

I'm new to Java/Android so I apologize if this is a basic schoolboy error!

TIA for any advice

John

Comment: Let me clarify, is your app playing music, when you click on Home button, the music stops and when you load the app again your music plays from the beginning instead of where it had left off?

Comment: It stops and then replays from where it was before HOME was pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Programming applications for Android is a bit different then programming for conventional operating systems. Android stops your application when it looses focus. You'll have to read about [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife). If you're creating some kind of music player you should consider using a background service with a worker thread.